# Shrinking popover on a Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a popover inside a Twitter Bootstrap modal as a way of displaying hints in a form. At first sight, everything seems working OK; However, looking closely, I find that no matter what I put into the popover, the container shrinks itself to its minimum possible width – even though there's plenty of space for it to expand to fit its contents in one line.

You can see the phenomenon in this screenshot:

[image: The problem]

(You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/swBYA/ – click on the big button to show the modal, then on the input to show the popover)

If you inspect the popover element, you'll see that it has no fixed width, and its `max-width` exceeds its actual computed width.

Editing the component's `width` and setting it to a fixed number does change the width as expected, but it's not clean, as some popovers will become unnecessarily big.

Setting `white-space` to `nowrap` makes the container expand to fit its content as expected, but this of course breaks the `max-width`.

Changing the container's `position` from `absolute` to `relative` makes the container behave as expected, but the alignment gets messed up. I think this suggests that the fact that it is absolutely positioned while being a child of the modal element must be affecting it somehow.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it so that the popover container will expand to fit its contents, while honoring the `max-width`?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Trick it out.

```
.popover.right { margin-right:-276px; }
```